# My apparently correct solution to NIMO Winter Fall #6

Tags: number-theory

Here's problem 6 of NIMO Winter Fall 2013:

Prove that for  all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\phi (2n-1) + \phi (2n+1) \geq 2 \phi (2n)$.

This is how we got it when we were working on the problem. Later it was identified as incorrect, and hence was modified. I solved the problem in its original form, and my solution is probably wrong. I would like to know where I messed up in the following solution.

First, note that no even number is coprime to $2n$. Hence, for every integer $n$, $\phi (2n) \leq n$. It suffices to show that 
$$\phi (2n-1) + \phi (2n+1) \geq 2n.$$
Now, let $S_k$ denote the set of all positive integers $\leq k$ which share at least one common prime factor with $k$. Note that $\phi (k)= k - |S_k|$. Thus, we have to show that:
$$ (2n+1)-|S_{2n+1}| + (2n-1) - |S_{2n-1}| \geq 2n \implies |S_{2n+1}|+|S_{2n-1}| \leq 2n. $$

Since $\gcd (2n-1, 2n+1)= 1$, $S_{2n+1} \cap S_{2n-1} = \emptyset$. It follows that $|S_{2n+1} \cup S_{2n-1}| = |S_{2n+1}|+|S_{2n-1}|$. But note that $S_{2n+1} \cup S_{2n-1} = M \cup \{2n+1\}$, where $M$ is a subset of $\{1, 2, \cdots , 2n-1\}$. Since $2n$ is coprime to both $2n-1$ and $2n+1$, it isn't included in $S_{2n-1} \cup S_{2n+1}$. Hence, $S_{2n-1} \cup S_{2n+1}$ has atmost $2n$ elements, and the desired result follows. $\blacksquare$

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't follow that $S_{2n-1}$ and $S_{2n+1}$ are disjoint just because $\gcd (2n-1,2n+1) = 1$.

Let $n = 13$, then $15$ shares a common prime factor with $2n-1 = 25$ as well as with $2n +1 = 27$.

Comment: Thanks! I was so silly, sorry. :(

Comment: Don't be sorry. It's an easy mistake to make. I didn't spot it immediately either.

Answer (score 4):

The mistake is very subtle.

$gcd(2n-1,2n+1)=1$ does NOt imply $S_{2n+1} \cap S_{2n-1} = \emptyset$.

For example, if $2n-1=33=3 \cdot 11, 2n+1=35=5\cdot 7$ we have

$$3 \cdot 5 \in S_{2n+1} \cap S_{2n-1} \,.$$